# validation accuracy is rounding to 3dp

Tags: python, validation, perceptron, rounding-error

This is my first time with `perceptron`, `ave perceptron` and `pegasos` models. I've written functions which have worked for various test cases thus far. But when I come to check accuracy, my validation accuracy values are all rounding down to **3 dp**.

Could this part of my code be the problem?

```
pred = np.where(decision > np.finfo(float).eps, 1.0, -1.0)
```

Edit:

changed that line to the following but it made no impact on the validation accuracy output.

```
pred = np.where(decision >= 1e-16, 1.0, -1.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that all of the answers should have been 3dp because was dividing by 500.
The actual problem for why my answers didn't match the online grader for this project, was a Pycharm plugins/encoding error.
It was fixed by reinstalling everything.
Apparently other people had the same incorrect results by not correctly specifying the filepath to some files we needed to read in.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).